# Compile list of nomenclature and list of acronyms

Tags: glossaries, texmaker, acronyms

I'm trying to print out a list with acronyms and another list with nomenclature. The list with Nomenclature prints without problem but I can't see the list with acronyms.I'm compiling with

> PDFLatex -> Makeindex -> PDFLatex

and using Texmaker as my IDE.

This is my code:

TesisDeGrado.tex

```
\documentclass[11 pt, letterpaper, twoside, openright]{icontec}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % Manejo de idiomas
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pages = some]{background} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{LISTA DE SÍMBOLOS}


%Acronym definitions
\newacronym{ese}{ESE}{Empresa Social del Estado}

% nomenclature:

\newglossaryentry{angelsperarea}{
  name = $a$ ,
  description = The number of angels per unit area,
}
\newglossaryentry{numofangels}{
  name = $N$ ,
  description = The number of angels per needle point
}
\newglossaryentry{areaofneedle}{
  name = $A$ ,
  description = The area of the needle point
}


\backgroundsetup{
contents={\includegraphics[natwidth=1300,natheight=1700]{escudounipamplona.png}},
angle=0, 
scale=0.45, 
color=black, 
opacity=0.1
}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\BgThispage
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
{
\huge\textbf{Diseño de políticas mantenimiento basadas en ingeniería de confiabilidad y propuesta para la mejora operacional a equipos electromecánicos del Hospital Universitario Erasmo Meoz de Cúcuta}  

\vspace{5cm}
{\normalsize \textit{Autor}} \\
Juan David Bola\~nos Aguilar\\

\vspace{5cm}
Programa de ingeniería mecatrónica \\
Departamento de ingeniería mecánica, mecatrónica e industrial \\
Facultad de ingenierías y arquitectura\\
Universidad de Pamplona\\
Villa del Rosario, Norte de Santander\\
febrero del 2015\\
}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}


\BgThispage
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
{
\Large\textbf{Diseño de políticas mantenimiento basadas en ingeniería de confiabilidad y propuesta para la mejora operacional a equipos electromecánicos del Hospital Universitario Erasmo Meoz de Cúcuta} 

\vspace{2cm}
{\small \textit{Autor}} \\
Juan David Bola\~nos Aguilar \\
{\small \textit{Codigo: 1116249797}} \\
{\small\textit{Correo electronico: judabo@unipamplona.edu.co}} 

\vspace{1cm}
{\small \textit{Practica laboral para optar al titulo de}}\\
Ingeniero mecatrónico

\vspace{1cm}
{\small\textit{Director}} \\
MSc. Oscar Manuel Duque Suarez\\
{\small\textit{Master en controles industriales}} \\
{\small \textit{Correo electrónico: omduque@unipamplona.edu.co}} 

\vspace{0.5cm}
{\small\textit{Supervisor}} \\
Ing. Rafael Antonio Sepulveda Ayala \\
{\small \textit{Coord. de mantenimiento, Hospital Universitario Erasmo Meoz}} 

\vspace{2cm}
Programa de ingeniería mecatrónica \\
Departamento de ingeniería mecánica, mecatrónica e industrial \\
Facultad de ingenierías y arquitectura\\
Universidad de Pamplona\\
Villa del Rosario, Norte de Santander\\
febrero del 2015\\
}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\hfill
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{c}
    Nota de aceptación:\\
    \hspace*{0.5\textwidth}\\\hline
    \\\hline
    \\\hline
    \\\hline
    \\\hline
    \\\hline
    \\\hline
    \\\hline
    \\\hline
    \vspace{3cm}\\\hline
    Firma del presidente del jurado
    \vspace{3cm}\\\hline
    Firma del jurado\\
    \vspace{3cm}\\\hline
    Firma del jurado
 \end{tabularx}

\vspace{4cm}
Ciudad y fecha (día, mes, año)
\newpage
\begin{flushright}
\null\vspace{\stretch{1}}
Aquí va la dedicatoria, la lista es larga...
\vspace{\stretch{2}}\null
\end{flushright}
\newpage

\begin{flushright}
\null\vspace{\stretch{1}}
Agradecimientos.
\vspace{\stretch{2}}\null
\end{flushright}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\printglossary[title=Nomenclatura]
\newpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abreviaturas]
\mainmatter
\include{intro}
\include{Chap1}


\end{document}
```

Chap1.tex:

```
\chapter{ESE Hospital Universitario Erasmo Meoz}
\label{Chap1}
\vspace{2cm}
\epigraph{El que ha comenzado bien, está a la mitad de la obra}{Horacio (65 A.C - 8 A.C)}
\vspace{2cm}
\section{RESEÑA HISTÓRICA}
\subsection{Marco legal y actos administrativos de creación.}
Se necesitaron mas de 40 años para que fueran escuchadas las solicitudes reiteradas hechas por el cuerpo médico, autoridades asistenciales, políticas y comunitarias de Cúcuta para que se determinara el momento de construir un nuevo hospital para cubrir las necesidades de salud de los nortesantandereanos. Es así como el Hospital Universitario Erasmo Meoz es producto de la Ley 39 de 1969 por medio de la cual se implementó el Plan Hospitalario Nacional; plan que fue presentado por el Senador León Colmenares Baptista.

Posteriormente la ley 43, de diciembre 31 de 1973; por medio de la cual la Nación se asocia al primer centenario de la reconstrucción de la ciudad de Cúcuta, en su artículo 7º plantea: El Gobierno Nacional impulsará la terminación de las siguientes obras actualmente en ejecución:a) Construcción y dotación del Hospital Erasmo Meoz de Cúcuta cuya edificación fue comenzada en 1973 mediante contrato entre la Nación, el Departamento Norte de Santander y la Beneficencia de Norte de Santander.

Fue autorizada su creación como ente jurídico mediante ordenanza 019 de la Honorable Asamblea Departamental el día 2 de diciembre de 1986 con el nombre del Doctor Erasmo Meoz, posteriormente el decreto 000293 expedido por la gobernación del Departamento el 2 de abril de 1987, reglamentó su constitución.

En la década de los 90 y de conformidad con lo dispuesto en la ordenanza 00060 del 29 de diciembre de 1995 emanada por la Asamblea departamental, el Hospital Universitario Erasmo Meoz se transformó en la Empresa Social del estado Hospital Erasmo Meoz, una entidad pública descentralizada del orden departamental con personería jurídica, patrimonio propio, autonomía administrativa, sometida al régimen jurídico de los artículos 194, 195 y 197 de la Ley 100 de 1993 y sus decretos reglamentarios.

En noviembre 27 de 2003, mediante ordenanza 00038, la honorable asamblea del departamento de Norte de Santander modificó la denominación de la entidad quedando de la siguiente forma: \gls{ese} HOSPITAL UNIVERSITARIO ERASMO MEOZ, tal como se conoce en la actualidad.

\subsection{Construcción y funcionamiento.}
La construcción del hospital se inició en marzo de 1972 y duró 15 años, esta se inició en un lote donado por el municipio de Cúcuta, la obra fue llevada a cabo por el consorcio DARIO M. DAMATO y GUSTAVO VELA \& CIA LTDA, la obra fue asesorada por el Fondo Nacional Hospitalario, los acabados los realizó la firma de Alfredo E. Vargas Ramírez por contrato de administración delegada y la administración técnica del arquitecto Gustavo Álvarez Gutiérrez quien además se encargó del proyecto de dotación y organización inicial del hospital.

El hospital inicia sus labores en forma escalonada a partir del 15 de octubre de 1987, atendiendo primero la demanda en medicina general en 36 centros y puestos de salud de su entonces denominada área de influencia. El día 19 de noviembre de 1987 , se dio al servicio el departamento de ginecobstetricia con 65 camas, luego en enero 04 de 1988 el departamento de pediatría inició su atención con 63 camas, el 28 de marzo de 1988 inició labores medicina interna con 42 camas y el 30 de marzo del mismo año el servicio de cirugía general con 105 camas; a mediados de 1988 quedaron habilitadas 325 camas.

Un año después de su entrada en funcionamiento (1988) la planta de personal del hospital, ascendía a 1100 funcionarios, siendo la mayor parte de sus trabajadores los que laboraban en el antiguo hospital San Juan de Dios, también se vinculó al personal de la clínica infantil Teresa Briceño de Andressen y del hospital sanatorio Amelia.

\subsection{Premios y distinciones recibidas.}
Como consecuencia de la aplicación y cumplimiento de los compromisos derivados del convenio de desempeño 475 de 1999, en ceremonia especial en la CASA DE NARIÑO el 5 de mayo de 2004, el señor presidente de la república, Doctor Álvaro Uribe Vélez otorgó el PREMIO NACIONAL DE ALTA GERENCIA a la ESE HOSPITAL ERASMO MEOZ DE CUCUTA. (PRIMER PUESTO), por el documento denominado “ PROCESO DE REESTRUCTURACIÓN DE LA ESE HOSPITAL ERASMO MEOZ (ESE – HEM) DE CÚCUTA, ANÁLISIS Y RESULTADOS DE LA EXPERIENCIA 4 AÑOS DESPUÉS ”; experiencia que el Gobierno Nacional inscribió en el Banco de Éxitos de la Administración Pública.

Así mismo por haber logrado el primer lugar en el Premio Nacional de Alta Gerencia (2003-2004), el gobierno nacional a través del departamento Administrativo de la Función Publica; postuló en diciembre de 2005 a la entidad ESE HOSPITAL UNIVERSITARIO ERASMO MEOZ al Premio de Naciones Unidas, premio que se otorga a nivel internacional, la entidad fue inscrita en la categoría Nº 2 “ Mejorando la prestación de los servicios ”, el cual se entregó en la reunión anual del consejo de seguridad de las naciones unidas en Nueva York, en junio 23 de 2006, por América Latina el ganador de la categoría fue el estado brasileño de Bahía. Este concurso se realiza anualmente desde el año 2003 y se ha convertido en una herramienta efectiva para resaltar las mejores prácticas e innovaciones en el Servicio Público a nivel mundial.

\subsection{Conformación de la E.S.E Hospital Universitario Erasmo Meoz.}

\subsubsection{Estructura organizativa.}
La estructura organizativa y órganos de dirección de la entidad están distribuidos de la siguiente forma:
\begin{enumerate}
\item  Dirección: Conformada por la Junta Directiva, compuesta por seis miembros de diferentes estamentos del departamento y el Gerente de la ESE.
\item Atención al usuario: Conformado por la Sub-Gerencia de Servicios de Salud y cuatro secciones: Apoyo a la Atención, Servicios Hospitalarios, Servicios Quirúrgicos y Servicios Ambulatorios.
\item Logística Comprende la Sub-Gerencia Administrativa la cual tiene a cargo tres secciones: Talento Humano, Recursos Físicos y Financiera.
\end{enumerate}

\gls{ese} is an abbreviation whereas
\gls{angelsperarea}, \gls{numofangels} and \gls{areaofneedle} are part of the
nomenclature

\subsubsection{•}
```

EDIT: icontec.cls and icontec.sty files

[icontec.cls and icontec.sty files](https://db.tt/ewmU4fYw)

Comment: Where can we find `icontec.cls`?

Comment: I'm going to post a dropbox link with these two files @ChristianHupfer

Comment: I think, it works without the class too...

Comment: Have you run `makeglossaries` on `TesisDeGrado`?

Comment: I'm running PDFLatex -> Makeindex -> PDFLatex.  Makeindex with the following commands: makeindex -s build/%.ist -o build/%.gls build/%.glo

Comment: No, you must have the `makeglossaries build/%` step between `pdflatex` and `makeindex`. I am compiling by hand on terminal.

Comment: it works for you?

Comment: What commands are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the document above (and replacing the class by `scrbook` for lazyness) I compile by hand on a Linux terminal this way (one can glue the several commands with a `;` of course in bash):

> pdflatex TesisDeGrado.tex
>
> makeglossaries TesisDeGrado
>
> makeindex -s TesisDeGrado.ist -o TesisDeGrado.glo TesisDeGrado.gls
>
> pdflatex TesisDeGrado.tex

This gives the output:

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to add the aditional makeglossaries step in Texmaker?

Comment: @jd1215 [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154767)

Comment: @jd1215: I don't use TeXMaker , but I'll try... but Johannes_B already posted a link ;-)

Comment: @jd1215: Well, the TeXMaker allows for user commands to be added. Use `makeglossaries %` as a new entry for such user command as described in the TeXMaker section in Johannes' link

Comment: It needs a bit of thinking, but TeXmaker really does not care if the script is `arara` or `latexmk` or `biber` or `makeglossaries`.